# After Converting DataFrame with to_csv method, I cannot find it on my computer

Tags: python, linux, pandas, csv

I'm doing my first Machine Learning project on Kaggle and managed to stumble my way to an output file. I am also new to Linux so trying to figure that out at the same time.

I can write to csv successfully and read the csv file...but I cannot find the file on my computer

```
#Runs with no error
titanic_01.to_csv('/home/myname/titanic_final_prediction.csv')     

#Reads the Dataframe object with no issues
pd.read_csv('/home/myname/titanic_final_prediction.csv')
```

However in Terminal the file does not appear in the `/home/myname/` directory or anywhere on my computer if I do a search

Any help appreciated.

Comment: what do you get when you run this command in a terminal `ls -l /home/myname/titanic_final_prediction.csv'`

Comment: I just get this....

(eikwueze@penguin:~$ ls -l /home/myname/titanic_final_prediction.csv'
>)

Comment: Run without the ' at the end

Comment: I get....ls: cannot access '/home/myname/titanic_final_prediction.csv': No such file or directory

Comment: Found a solution, files are stored in '/kaggle/working' so downloaded from there